# Getting average of calculated list haskell

Tags: haskell, fold

I have

```
avgRatingsForDirector :: String -> [Film] -> [Int]
avgRatingsForDirector _ [] = []
avgRatingsForDirector requestedDirector ((Film _ director _ ((_, rating):ratings)):restOfFilms)
    | requestedDirector == director = [rating] ++ avgRatingsForDirector requestedDirector restOfFilms
    | otherwise = avgRatingsForDirector requestedDirector restOfFilms
```

This outputs a list of numbers, I want to have the result be the average of these numbers. is is possible to use the foldr function on the result somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your function as is and post-process its result with a function to calculate an average of any list of numbers.

One way to code it so it does only one traversal of the list is

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import Data.List

avg :: (Integral a, Fractional b) => [a] -> b
avg xs = g $ foldl' c (0,0) xs
 where
   c (!a,!n) x = (a+x,n+1)
   g (a,n) = fromIntegral a / fromIntegral n
```

Bang patterns make the calculation efficient.

see also: [The Most Fuun You Can Have: Beautiful Folding](http://squing.blogspot.com/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html)